# python redis rpush for loop failed

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I use redis in python. I try to insert file names into redis. Here's how I do it:

```
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(".") 
  if f.endswith('.txt') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(".", f))]
for x in onlyfiles:
   r.rpush('filename', x)
```

My code failed in r.rpush(). The error as below:

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

How can I insert the file name correctly?

Comment: Have you verified that the key `filename` is a list? `TYPE filename`

Comment: filename is a string. I want to create list with 'filename' as key.

Comment: I mean **on REDIS*. What is the type in REDIS?

Comment: the type of filename is "none"

Comment: The error you are getting signifies that the command is being run against a key that holds the wrong type. `RPUSH` would create a new list with the elements specified if the key did not exist.